# SQL - Calculate 2 columns and view result to another to column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have this query where I can get my customer balance to be use as reporting later. But I am kinda stuck on this part where the 2 columns should calculate and view the result to another column the harder part is they are on the different row. So here's my query

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY DR.id )                  AS 'NO.' ,          
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), CAST(DR.doc_date AS DATE), 100)  AS 'DOC DATE',
       v.which AS 'DOC TYPE',
        CASE WHEN 
            v.which IN ('NET TOTAL', 'DELL/COL/CHARGE') THEN V.val
            END AS DEBIT,
        CASE WHEN 
            v.which IN ('CDW', 'PAYMENT') THEN V.val
            END AS CREDIT,
        CAST(v.val AS float) + CAST(v.val AS float)  AS 'BALANCE'

FROM [dbo].[doc_customer] DC 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[doc_rent] DR ON DR.doc_sourced_customer_id = DC.id 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[slip_rent] SR ON SR.doc_sourced_doc_rent_id = DR.id 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[slip_rent_payment] SP ON SP.doc_sourced_rent_id = DR.id OUTER APPLY
     (VALUES ('NET TOTAL', SR.net_total),
             ('DELL/COL/CHARGE', SR.dell_col_charge),
             ('CDW', SR.CDW),
             ('PAYMENT', sp.amount)
     ) v(which, val)
WHERE DC.id = '1-1---1-1-1---1--1~1' 
AND DR.deleted = 0
AND DR.void = 0
AND v.val IS NOT NULL 
AND v.val <> '' ;
```

As u can see in my query I can get the DEBIT and CREDIT value but my problem is 
on how to get total of their calculation.

---

My Desired Output

```
  | NO. | DOC DATE    | DOC TYPE  | DEBIT | CREDIT | BALANCE 
-------------------------------------------------------------
1 | 1   | Mar 28 2017 | NET TOTAL | 341   | NULL   | 
2 | 2   | Mar 28 2017 | PAYMENT   | NULL  | 4000   | -3659
3 | 3   | Oct 16 2017 | NET TOTAL | 150   | NULL   | -3509
4 | 4   | Oct 16 2017 | CDW       | NULL  | 50     | -3559
5 | 5   | Oct 16 2017 | PAYMENT   | NULL  | 150    | -3709
```

Here's the link for my desired output [sql desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdMOZ.png)

Comment: I added the desired output as formatted text as well as not everyone can open images and not all devices can clearly read the images on their small screen. While this is referring to code it also applies very much for important information like current and expected outputs ► [**Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know stackoverflow can do like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this is SQL Server 2012 or higher, you want `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` like this (notice you need an indexer, so I chose [No.] :

```
SELECT [NO.], Debit, Credit, 
  SUM(coalesce(Debit,0) - coalesce(Credit,0)) OVER(ORDER BY [NO.] 
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
          AS BALANCE
FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY DR.id )                  AS 'NO.' ,          
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), CAST(DR.doc_date AS DATE), 100)  AS 'DOC DATE',
       v.which AS 'DOC TYPE',
        CASE WHEN 
            v.which IN ('NET TOTAL', 'DELL/COL/CHARGE') THEN V.val
            END AS DEBIT,
        CASE WHEN 
            v.which IN ('CDW', 'PAYMENT') THEN V.val
            END AS CREDIT,
        CAST(v.val AS float) + CAST(v.val AS float)  AS 'BALANCE'

FROM [dbo].[doc_customer] DC 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[doc_rent] DR ON DR.doc_sourced_customer_id = DC.id 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[slip_rent] SR ON SR.doc_sourced_doc_rent_id = DR.id 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[slip_rent_payment] SP ON SP.doc_sourced_rent_id = DR.id OUTER APPLY
     (VALUES ('NET TOTAL', SR.net_total),
             ('DELL/COL/CHARGE', SR.dell_col_charge),
             ('CDW', SR.CDW),
             ('PAYMENT', sp.amount)
     ) v(which, val)
WHERE DC.id = '1-1---1-1-1---1--1~1' 
AND DR.deleted = 0
AND DR.void = 0
AND v.val IS NOT NULL 
AND v.val <> ''
) a
```